# Using TFI/DF and CountVectorizer in a pipeline/gridSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use TFI/DF and CountVectorizer in one pipeline.
i did the following:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('tfic', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('cvec',  CountVectorizer()),
    ('lr' ,LogisticRegression())
])
```

and the parameters:

```
pipe_parms = {
    'cvec__max_features' : [100,500],
    'cvec__ngram_range' : [(1,1),(1,2)],
    'cvec__stop_words' : [ 'english', None]
}
```

gridSearch:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid= pipe_parms, cv=3)
```

I got an error

> lower not found.

Using either `countVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` works, but not both.

i read other questions on stackoverflow and they indicated that i should be using `TfidfTransformer()` instead if i want both to work using one pipeline.
Doing that, i am getting an error 'could not convert string to float'

Is there a way to use the two vectorizores in one pipeline? or what other methods do you suggest.

Thank you

Edit:
I found a solution to combine 2 parallel transformers (count and Tfidf vectorizers in this case) by using FeatureUnion.
I wrote a short blog post about it here: 
https://link.medium.com/OPzIU0T3N0

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, my explanation make you clearer about what happens here.

First you tried to apply `TfidfVectorizer` transform. This will change the collection of texts into TfidfVector, which consists of numbers. Say you have this list of texts

```
texts = [
    'I am a bird',
    'a crow is a bird',
    'bird fly high in the sky',
    'bird bird bird',
    'black bird in the dead of night',
    'crow is black bird'
]
```

running

```
TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(texts).todense()
```

will results in

```
matrix([[0.91399636, 0.40572238, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.35748457, 0.        , 0.66038049, 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.66038049, 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
...])
```

Then, from this matrix of numbers, you tried to apply `CountVectorizer`, which I don't think what you would wanted. Without `Pipeline`, your code would be like

```
CountVectorizer().fit_transform(
    TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(texts).todense()
)
```

according to [scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) `CountVectorizer` accept sequence of string or bytes instead of number.

> **Is there a way to use the two vectorizers in one pipeline? or what other methods do you suggest?**

I suggest you used either one of `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer`, don't use both in 1 pipeline. In layman terms, `CountVectorizer` will output the frequency of each word in a collection of string that you passed, while `TfidfVectorizer` will also output the *normalized* frequency of each word. That being said, both methods serve the same purpose: changing collection of texts into numbers using frequency. Thus, you should use only one of them.

will be happy to add my answer if you elaborate more, why did you want to use both vectorizer in one pipeline.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that helped in explaining different things that I wasn’t aware of. I found that using FeatureUnion can actually allow you to do both vectorizers in one Pipeline. I wrote this about it. https://link.medium.com/OPzIU0T3N0